# How to create a object specific quick action on Campaign member?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, campaign-member, quickaction

I have a requirement to convert onclick JavaScript button on campaignMember object to lightning compatible button. I created a lightning component handling the logic of the onclick javascript button and planned to create a quick action on CampaignMember and assign the lightning component created to the Quick action. But unfortunately I don't see any option to create a quick action on CampaignMember. Anyone has an idea on how to handle this scenario?

The button onclick directs to a custom component with few passed parameters for creating a new record of a different object.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to succeed this challenge by embedding lightning component in a VF page and created a custom button URL with the VF page.

Comment: Sorry to ask, bbut can I know the reason for -ve vote @Adrian Larson

Comment: I made no vote. I can't help you there.